# How to build C++ program with libjpeg library

Tags: c++, gcc, libjpeg

I'd like to build C++ program with libjpeg library, but when I try to build it, I get errors below.

```
g++ main.cpp -o main.o
main.cpp:26:22: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-    Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
char *filename = "output.jpg";
                 ^
1 warning generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_jpeg_CreateCompress", referenced from:
      _main in main-sUpMU6.o
  "_jpeg_destroy_compress", referenced from:
      _main in main-sUpMU6.o
  "_jpeg_finish_compress", referenced from:
      _main in main-sUpMU6.o
  "_jpeg_set_defaults", referenced from:
      _main in main-sUpMU6.o
  "_jpeg_set_quality", referenced from:
      _main in main-sUpMU6.o
  "_jpeg_start_compress", referenced from:
      _main in main-sUpMU6.o
  "_jpeg_std_error", referenced from:
      _main in main-sUpMU6.o
  "_jpeg_stdio_dest", referenced from:
      _main in main-sUpMU6.o
  "_jpeg_write_scanlines", referenced from:
      _main in main-sUpMU6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

The structure of my project is like this.

```
./myCodes
  main.h main.cpp Makefile
./jpeg-9
  libjpeg src and build outputs
```

Make file is like this.

```
ulibjpeg: main.o
    g++ -v -L../jpeg-9/cjpeg -L../jpeg-9/djpeg -L../jpeg-9 -l../jpeg-9 -ljpeg main.o -o     ulibjpeg

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ main.cpp -o main.o
```

I think I have to add libraries of libjpeg, but which files do I have to add and how can I add add that libraries in g++ options?

Here's the files of ./jpeg-9 directories.

```
Makefile    jccoefct.c  jcprepct.lo jdmarker.o  jmemmgr.lo  makefile.bcc    rdjpgcom.1
Makefile.am jccoefct.lo jcprepct.o  jdmaster.c  jmemmgr.o   makefile.dj rdjpgcom.c
Makefile.in jccoefct.o  jcsample.c  jdmaster.lo jmemname.c  makefile.manx   rdjpgcom.o
README      jccolor.c   jcsample.lo jdmaster.o  jmemnobs.c  makefile.mc6    rdppm.c
aclocal.m4  jccolor.lo  jcsample.o  jdmerge.c   jmemnobs.lo makefile.mms    rdppm.o
ar-lib      jccolor.o   jctrans.c   jdmerge.lo  jmemnobs.o  makefile.sas    rdrle.c
cderror.h   jcdctmgr.c  jctrans.lo  jdmerge.o   jmemsys.h   makefile.unix   rdrle.o
cdjpeg.c    jcdctmgr.lo jctrans.o   jdpostct.c  jmorecfg.h  makefile.vc rdswitch.c
cdjpeg.h    jcdctmgr.o  jdapimin.c  jdpostct.lo jpegint.h   makefile.vms    rdswitch.o
cdjpeg.o    jchuff.c    jdapimin.lo jdpostct.o  jpeglib.h   makefile.wat    rdtarga.c
change.log  jchuff.lo   jdapimin.o  jdsample.c  jpegtran    makejdep.vc6    rdtarga.o
cjpeg       jchuff.o    jdapistd.c  jdsample.lo jpegtran.1  makejdsp.vc6    stamp-h1
cjpeg.1     jcinit.c    jdapistd.lo jdsample.o  jpegtran.c  makejdsw.vc6    structure.txt
cjpeg.c     jcinit.lo   jdapistd.o  jdtrans.c   jpegtran.o  makejfil.v10    testimg.bmp
cjpeg.o     jcinit.o    jdarith.c   jdtrans.lo  jquant1.c   makejmak.vc6    testimg.jpg
ckconfig.c  jcmainct.c  jdarith.lo  jdtrans.o   jquant1.lo  makejsln.v10    testimg.ppm
coderules.txt   jcmainct.lo jdarith.o   jerror.c    jquant1.o   makejvcx.v10    testimgp.jpg
config.guess    jcmainct.o  jdatadst.c  jerror.h    jquant2.c   makeproj.mac    testorig.jpg
config.log  jcmarker.c  jdatadst.lo jerror.lo   jquant2.lo  makerdep.vc6    testprog.jpg
config.status   jcmarker.lo jdatadst.o  jerror.o    jquant2.o   makerdsp.vc6    transupp.c
config.sub  jcmarker.o  jdatasrc.c  jfdctflt.c  jutils.c    makerfil.v10    transupp.h
configure   jcmaster.c  jdatasrc.lo jfdctflt.lo jutils.lo   makermak.vc6    transupp.o
configure.ac    jcmaster.lo jdatasrc.o  jfdctflt.o  jutils.o    makervcx.v10    usage.txt
depcomp     jcmaster.o  jdcoefct.c  jfdctfst.c  jversion.h  maketdep.vc6    wizard.txt
djpeg       jcomapi.c   jdcoefct.lo jfdctfst.lo libjpeg.la  maketdsp.vc6    wrbmp.c
djpeg.1     jcomapi.lo  jdcoefct.o  jfdctfst.o  libjpeg.map maketfil.v10    wrbmp.o
djpeg.c     jcomapi.o   jdcolor.c   jfdctint.c  libjpeg.txt maketmak.vc6    wrgif.c
djpeg.o     jconfig.bcc jdcolor.lo  jfdctint.lo libtool     maketvcx.v10    wrgif.o
example.c   jconfig.cfg jdcolor.o   jfdctint.o  ltmain.sh   makewdep.vc6    wrjpgcom
filelist.txt    jconfig.dj  jdct.h      jidctflt.c  makcjpeg.st makewdsp.vc6    wrjpgcom.1
install-sh  jconfig.h   jddctmgr.c  jidctflt.lo makdjpeg.st makewfil.v10    wrjpgcom.c
install.txt jconfig.mac jddctmgr.lo jidctflt.o  makeadsw.vc6    makewmak.vc6    wrjpgcom.o
jaricom.c   jconfig.manx    jddctmgr.o  jidctfst.c  makeasln.v10    makewvcx.v10    wrppm.c
jaricom.lo  jconfig.mc6 jdhuff.c    jidctfst.lo makecdep.vc6    makljpeg.st wrppm.o
jaricom.o   jconfig.sas jdhuff.lo   jidctfst.o  makecdsp.vc6    maktjpeg.st wrrle.c
jcapimin.c  jconfig.st  jdhuff.o    jidctint.c  makecfil.v10    makvms.opt  wrrle.o
jcapimin.lo jconfig.txt jdinput.c   jidctint.lo makecmak.vc6    missing     wrtarga.c
jcapimin.o  jconfig.vc  jdinput.lo  jidctint.o  makecvcx.v10    rdbmp.c             wrtarga.o
jcapistd.c  jconfig.vms jdinput.o   jinclude.h  makeddep.vc6    rdbmp.o
jcapistd.lo jconfig.wat jdmainct.c  jmemansi.c  makeddsp.vc6    rdcolmap.c
jcapistd.o  jcparam.c   jdmainct.lo jmemdos.c   makedfil.v10    rdcolmap.o
jcarith.c   jcparam.lo  jdmainct.o  jmemdosa.asm    makedmak.vc6    rdgif.c
jcarith.lo  jcparam.o   jdmarker.c  jmemmac.c   makedvcx.v10    rdgif.o
jcarith.o   jcprepct.c  jdmarker.lo jmemmgr.c   makefile.ansi   rdjpgcom
```

I'd like to use the program on multi-platform, so I'd rather not installed libjpeg library.

Comment: you forgot to link to the library and use `const char *filename = "output.jpg";`

Comment: thank you for your comment. Which files is the library and how can I add it? I'm a newbie, so I don't understand it...

Answer (score 1):

Use libjpeg in the compile command:

```
gcc main.c -ljpeg -o main.o
```

I wrote a tutorial for C: http://www.staerk.de/thorsten/C_Programming_Tutorial

Comment: thank you for your comment. I was able to build it, but I think the build command uses installed libjpeg library. I don't want to use installed libjpeg library, I want to use the libjpeg library that I builded myself perhaps in ./jpeg-9 directory.

Comment: I think the build command above uses the one of jpeg libraries shown below.

    Machida-no-MacBook-Air:ulibjpeg machidahiroaki$ sudo find /* -name jpeg
    /System/Library/Tcl/tcllib1.12/jpeg
    find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
    find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
    /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/graphics/jpeg
    /usr/share/file/magic/jpeg